# SQL Server : Variable inside the query string is not accessible outside

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic string based SQL scripts, the scripts does is to create a data coming from different tables and inserted into a temporary table. However, temporary table that have been created is not accessible outside of the string based scripts. Any idea on how to access the temp table?

Below is the sample scripts, I only show you the things that I need

```
DECLARE @x AS NVARCHAR(max)

SET @x = 'SELECT * into #persons FROM Persons Select * from #persons'

EXEC sp_executesql @x

--I need to access the temp table person below
Select #persons
```

Here is the link [sample code and data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35b6f/4) to the sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to scope issues (as you have seen), temp objects created in sub-processes are automatically dropped when that sub-process ends. So, you need to create the temp table prior to running the `EXEC`.

If you truly have a simply query that does not need to be dynamically put together (probably does not apply here but I figured it best to show various options), then you can do the `SELECT INTO` using a `WHERE 1 = 0` condition, or something similar, to force the query to return 0 rows:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM sys.objects WHERE 1 = 0;
```

In the case of dynamic SQL, you just need to create the temp table via CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (....);
```

Once either of those is done, then you can run the query via `sp_executesql`, but you cannot keep the `SELECT INTO` construct as it will create a new temp table local to that sub-process that will put you right back where you started in not being able to access the results outside of the `sp_executesql`.  You need to switch to using an `INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT ...` construct:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @x='INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT * FROM sys.objects;';

EXEC sp_executesql @x;

SELECT * FROM #tmp;
```

Alternatively, you can move the `INSERT INTO #tmp` outside of, and just above/before, the `sp_executesql` (as in Gordon's answer):

```
SET @x='SELECT * FROM sys.objects;';

INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC sp_executesql @x;
```

Temp tables are automatically dropped when the session ends, although you can drop them explicitly as well. In fact, the very reason you are having the problem of not being able to access the temp table that was created within the `sp_executesql` once that completes is because temp tables are automatically cleaned up :-).

Local temp tables (i.e. single # sign) are local to the session / `@@SPID` so it doesn't matter if 5 users or 500 users run this query.

Comment: Thanks for the details. The explanation is clear enough.

Comment: I need the information like this, very descriptive and it helps me a lot to understand what going behind the process.It gives me an idea on what needs to improve on creating SQL scripts. Actually the scripts are complex and very dynamic. The fields were dynamic and coming from different tables and there is information which needs to PIVOT just  to combine the results

Comment: O oh, I need to do like this CREATE TABLE outside just to make this run successfully. The problem is my columns are dynamic. So they won't solved the problem. Still I will work on the the string based instead of accessing outside the temp table. Do I am right?

Comment: @user3472262 : I needed to be alseep 2 hours ago so I can't stay up, but dynamic columns are very tricky and a separate question (I think it has been asked here before so you might find some info). If using SQL Server 2012 / 2014 you can: create #tmp with 1 column, submit the dynamic sql to `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx), loop through the results to build an ALTER statement to add the result columns, run the dynamic ALTER SQL, drop the original column, then run your dynamic `SELECT`. We can continue tomorrow in chat if needed.

Comment: @srutzky- Thank you for your time. I appreciate it a lot. I found a great article [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/701d7f4a-006a-47ea-9a38-d6417fde5d0b/how-to-create-dynamic-columns-in-a-temporary-table?forum=transactsql). I will still try your suggestion

Comment: @user3472262 : You are welcome. And yes, that link is showing the same idea that I mentioned. The only difference is that you need a way to determine what the result set fields will be. In that example they were contained in a table of meta-data. If you don't have that, then that is where `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` comes in.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this by creating a temporary table on the outside an executing the script.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @x AS NVARCHAR(max);

SET @x = N'SELECT * into #persons FROM Persons;
           Select * from #persons';

create table #Persons (
    . . . 
);

insert into #Persons
    exec(@x);
```

There are easier ways to retrieve a single value, but you seem to want an entire table.

Comment: If I created a table outside then I need to drop it after use?If there are 5 users using the query does it affects to the data that they getting to?

Comment: You can use a table variable instead.  But the temporary tables should be local to each connection.

Comment: Table variable can't be accessed inside the dynamic SQL, temporary table is local for the current session, so it is correct approach

Comment: Ok thanks I will stick to temp table instead as far as I understand that temp table will not affect the results for every users. But do i need to drop it after use or it will disposed automatically?

Comment: Overall this works, but there is no need to keep the `SELECT * INTO` query in the dynamic SQL; it only needs to be the `SELECT * FROM Persons;` portion (and yes, from the real Persons table, not the #person temp table, as there is no need to reference the temp table in this method of doing it).

Comment: @srutzky . . . I left that in because I suspect the OP was using short-hand for what the real query is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Understood, and that was pretty much the case, except that the `Select * from #persons` wasn't part of the real query; it was only to show that the `SELECT INTO` had worked. I commented above because by keeping it in, especially without using a new temp table name for outside of the dynamic SQL, it is unclear in what it is really doing: there are two INSERT operations and both _appear_ to be inserting into the same temp table. And it looks like the `SELECT * INTO` _should_ fail with `#persons already exists`, but it doesn't (which I feel is inconsistent and confusing behavior).

Comment: @srutzky . . . I don't think so.  The temporary tables are in different scopes, which is why you can't refer to the outer one from within the `exec`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : that's not true; you can access temp tables in a sub-process and it is a common way of passing arrays between stored procedures, especially prior to TVPs / XML. Try my example code. Run the part starting with `DECLARE` and it will error on no #tmp table exists. Then run the first example with `SELECT...WHERE 1=0` and re-run the 4 lines starting with `DECLARE`. It will work. This is the expected behavior. But if you do `SELECT * INTO #tmp` in the dynamic SQL, it creates a #tmp table specific to that "request" (execution in a session) and you lose access to #tmp created outside.

Comment: @srutzky . . . Thank you, I learned something new.  I just tried it and it *does* work.  It even seems to work in SQL Server 2008, where I was pretty sure it didn't work.  I must've confused it with the `into` version that doesn't work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : you are quite welcome. I haven't tried the "`SELECT * INTO #tmp` when a temp table of the same name had already been created in a parent process" test in anything prior to SQL 2012, but the ability to reference temp objects (tables and procs) in sub-processes should go back to at least SQL Server 2000 (definitely back to 2005).